# La opciones del menú del administrador de Django no aparecen en chrome

Tags: django, google-chrome, django-admin

Hola un saludo a tod@s

Estoy trabajando con Django y usando la librería Django suit.

Esta librería cambia el estilo del administrador, entre los cambios que realizan pone el menú al lado izquierdo con las opciones de los módulos y sus modelos en un sub-menu desplegable.

El problema es que este menú esta presentando una falla.

A algunos de los usuarios del aplicativo si les aparece y a otros no, como se puede ver en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi caso dejo de funcionar cuando borre el historial de navegación.

Alguien sabe a que se debe esta falla.

Nota: en la consola del navegador no se muestra ningún error.

Esta el la configuración en mi archivo `settings.py`

Sección installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'suit',
    'bootstrap3',
    ...
]
```

Sección templates

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates'))],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                "aplicaciones.lib.context_processors.augurio",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Probe en el navegador edge y el menú funciono bien, pase a firefox y también aparece el menú.

Borre el historial del navegador google chrome y sigue sin funcionar, lo extraño es que a otros usuarios si les funciona como debe ser; en ese navegador.

Comment: puede ser que la version de django que utilices no sea compatible con la version de django-suite

Comment: Pero estaba funcionado antes, en mi caso cuando borre el historial de navegación dejo de funcionar

Comment: parece que te falta configuracion mira https://django-suit.readthedocs.io/en/develop/getting_started.html#installation, trata de agregar la version de django

Comment: La configuración esta completa en el settings.py ya agregue la configuración en la pregunta.

Comment: Ya ejecute el comando ´python manage.py collectstatic´ e ingrese por el modo de incógnito para verificar que no fuera el cache, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: No puedo hacer el cambio en el ´DIRS´, me genera un error de template no encontrado

Comment: Acabo de probar en el navegador edge y e menú funciono bien, pase a firefox y también aparece el menú. Borrare nuevamente el historial de chrome para ver que sucede.

Comment: Borre el historial del navegador google chrome y sigue sin funcionar, lo extraño es que a  otros usuarios si les funciona como debe ser en ese navegador.

Comment: que version de django y python usas?

Comment: Python 2.7 y Django 1.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error es con Chrome, segun lo visto en su repositorio [Github](https://github.com/darklow/django-suit/issues/739) debes actualizar la versión de suit :

```
django-suit==0.2.28
```

Comment: Efectivamente, actualizar fue la solución. También tuve que borrar historial del cache y ejecutar el comando `python manage.py collectstatic`